# Changing number format in newmdtheoremenv or newtheorem

Tags: tikz-styles, mdframed, ntheorem

Using the mdframed package (with `[frame-method=tikz]`) I can create a new environment that resets every chapter with

`\newmdtheoremenv[<options>]{myenv}[<numberedlike>]{Sample}[chapter]`

The MWE below shows this in use where the output "Samples" are labelled 2.1, 2.2, etc. How do I change the numbering format to be 2-1, 2-2, etc.?

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\newmdtheoremenv{myenv}{Sample}[chapter]
% or \theoremenv{myenv}{Sample}[chapter]

\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}
Chapter content
\chapter{Second chapter}
Chapter content with samples
\begin{myenv}
My first sample
\end{myenv}
\begin{myenv}
My second sample
\end{myenv}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in the preamble add the lines

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@thmcountersep{-}
\makeatother
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@thmcountersep{-}
\makeatother
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\newmdtheoremenv{myenv}{Sample}[chapter]
\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}
Chapter content
\chapter{Second chapter}
Chapter content with samples
\begin{myenv}
My first sample
\end{myenv}
\begin{myenv}
My second sample
\end{myenv}
\end{document}
```